# Get t-1 value (from previous cell) in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to create new columns where each row has the value of the previous row (the day before).

My data is formatted like that (in the orginal file there are 12 columns plus the timestamp and thousands of rows):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp" : ['1993-11-01' ,'1993-11-02', '1993-11-03', '1993-11-04','1993-11-15'], "Austria" : [6.11 ,6.18, 6.17, 6.17, 6.40],"Belgium" : [7.01, 7.05, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6],"France" : [7.69, 7.61, 7.67, 7.91, 8.61]},index = [1, 2, 3,4,5])
```

**What I have:**

```
Timestamp       Austria Belgium France
1   1993-11-01  6.11    7.01    7.69
2   1993-11-02  6.18    7.05    7.61
3   1993-11-03  6.17    7.20    7.67
4   1993-11-04  6.17    7.50    7.91
5   1993-11-15  6.40    7.60    8.61
```

**What I want:**

```
Timestamp       Austria t-1 Belgium t-1 France t-1
1   1993-11-01  NaN         NaN         NaN
2   1993-11-02  6.11        7.01        7.69
3   1993-11-03  6.18        7.05        7.61
4   1993-11-04  6.17        7.20        7.67
5   1993-11-15  6.17        7.50        7.91
```

Its easy in Excel but I cannot find a way to do that in Python. But surely there is a way. Anyone knows how to do to it?

Comment: You could Use shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) on the columns to compute:

```
cols = ["Austria", "Belgium", "France"]
df[cols] = df[cols].shift()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Timestamp  Austria  Belgium  France
1  1993-11-01      NaN      NaN     NaN
2  1993-11-02     6.11     7.01    7.69
3  1993-11-03     6.18     7.05    7.61
4  1993-11-04     6.17     7.20    7.67
5  1993-11-15     6.17     7.50    7.91
```

As an alternative:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].shift()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

First [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `Timestamp` column, then use [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
In [4400]: d = df.set_index('Timestamp').shift()
In [4403]: d.columns = [i + ' t-1' for i in d.columns]

In [4406]: d.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [4407]: d
Out[4407]: 
    Timestamp  Austria t-1  Belgium t-1  France t-1
0  1993-11-01          NaN          NaN         NaN
1  1993-11-02         6.11         7.01        7.69
2  1993-11-03         6.18         7.05        7.61
3  1993-11-04         6.17         7.20        7.67
4  1993-11-15         6.17         7.50        7.91
```